# How to divide the indices to determine the ideal number of clusters in 3 groups?

Tags: cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, distance, similarity, hierarchical-clustering

How to divide the following indices to determine the ideal number of clusters in 3 groups: internal cohesion (intracluster similarity),
distance between cluster (intercluster dissimilarity) or both?

Duda (Duda e Hart, 1973)
Pseudo-T² (Duda e Hart, 1973)
C-index (Hubert and Levin, 1976)
Gamma (Baker and Hubert, 1975)
Beale (Beale , 1969)
Cubic Clustering Criterion (Sarle, 1983)
PtBiserial (Milligan, 1981)
Gplus (Rohlf, 1974)
Frey (Frey and Van Groenewoud, 1972)
Hartigan (Hartigan, 1975)
Tau (Rohlf, 1974)
Ratkowsky (Ratkowsky and Lance, 1978)
Marriot (Marriot, 1971)
Ball (Ball and Hall, 1965)
TraceCovW (Milligan and Cooper, 1985)
TraceW (Milligan and Cooper, 1985)
Friedman (Friedman and Rubin, 1967)
Mcclain (McClain and Rao, 1975)

I looked in several references and there is no consensus in several indexes.